# How to change Solr JVM arguments?

Tags: solr, jvm, resource-loading

Where & how exactly do I change this setting in Solr 7.7.3?:

```
   set -Dsolr.allow.unsafe.resourceloading=true to allow unsafe loading
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to add as `solr.allow.unsafe.resourceloading=true` to `solr.in.sh` file,

This file can be found under the path `"...\solr-VERSION\bin"`

Here is how you can add the entries in the file mentioned.

```
SOLR_RESOURCE_LOAD="-Dsolr.allow.unsafe.resourceloading=true"
SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS $SOLR_RESOURCE_LOAD"
```

Comment: the '=' sign should be joined with the surrounding characters.  Minor mistake, but this solution was clear and it worked. Thanks